# how many classes h2o deep learning algorithm accepts?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, h2o, multilabel-classification

I want to predict the response variable, and it has 700 classes.

Deep learning model parameters

```
from h2o.estimators import deeplearning

dl_model = deeplearning.H2ODeepLearningEstimator(
                                    hidden=[200,200],
                                    epochs  = 10,
                                missing_values_handling='MeanImputation',
                                max_categorical_features=4,
                                distribution='multinomial'
                            )

# Train the model
dl_model.train(x = Content_vecs.names,
                y='tags',
               training_frame   = data_split[0],
               validation_frame = data_split[1]
               )

Orginal Response Variable -Tags: 
apps, email, mail
finance,freelancers,contractors,zen99
genomes
gogovan
brazil,china,cloudflare
hauling,service,moving
ferguson,crowdfunding,beacon
cms,naytev
y,combinator
in,store,
conversion,logic,ad,attribution

Response variable tags: 
[74]
[156, 89]
[153, 13, 133, 40]
[150]
[474, 277, 113]
[181, 117]
[15, 87, 8, 11]
```

Error:

OSError: Job with key $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_8355bcac0e9e98a86257f45c180e4898 failed with an exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: error cannot be computed: too many classes

stacktrace: 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: error cannot be computed: too many classes
    at hex.ConfusionMatrix.err(ConfusionMatrix.java:92)

But in h2o-core/src/main/java/hex/ConfusionMatrix.javaConfusionMatrix.java
  is written that it can compute 1000 classes.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you have 700 classes, do you mean your response variable is made up of *arrays* of those 700 unique numbers? Because you gave this example:

```
Response variable tags: 
[74]
[156, 89]
[153, 13, 133, 40]
[150]
[474, 277, 113]
[181, 117]
[15, 87, 8, 11]
```

H2O cannot predict arrays. Each unique combination of numbers will be counting as a single class. You therefore likely have a lot more than 700 classes, from H2O's point of view.

If you look at the data over on Flow ( http://127.0.0.1:54321/ ) it will tell you how many unique levels there are in 'tags'. (You can also get it from the python API, using `describe()` on the frame, or `categories()` on the column in question will list all the levels.)

Your next question is going to be what to do about this. I suggest making that a new question, where you explain what the 700 values, and the arrays represent; it is almost certainly going to involve some domain-specific pre-processing. However you could try playing with `categorical_encoding` http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/categorical_encoding.html

Comment: Yes, the response variable is made up of arrays of those 700 unique numbers, but I want to predict the two or three numbers on one row, not the arrays. So if I want to predict the numbers so how my response variable looks like before passing to deep learning and what would be my categorical_encoding either it is eigen or a label_encoder